# Can pandas' to_datetime() method fail on one column, but not the others?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, types, casting

I am trying to convert data types in a project I'm doing. I am given the planned and actual dates and times of some trains, and the dataset looks like this:
[`data.info()`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7hKK.png)

All dates and times are of the form YYYY-MM-DD and HH:MM:SS. Now, I created the datetime columns, in order to convert them easily into datetimes and drop a few uninformative columns, and I did it like so:

```
belgium_trains['Planned arrival datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(belgium_trains['Planned arrival date'].str.cat(belgium_trains['Planned arrival time'], ' '))
belgium_trains['Actual arrival datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(belgium_trains['Actual arrival date'].str.cat(belgium_trains['Actual arrival time'], ' '))
belgium_trains['Planned departure datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(belgium_trains['Planned departure date'].str.cat(belgium_trains['Planned departure time'], ' '))
belgium_trains['Actual departure datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(belgium_trains['Actual departure date'].str.cat(belgium_trains['Actual departure time'], ' '))
```

Now, all columns get converted to `datetime64[ns]`, except Planned departure datetime, which is still an object. If I use `utc = True` as a parameter on its call to `pd.to_datetime()` I get an error message about it not being tz-aware. But on the rest of the columns it works just fine.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqMlF.png) is the 4 columns after the conversion, which to me look the same. And what's even weirder, is that if I separate the instructions instead of pd.to_datetime() on the string builder, it works.

Can anybody explain to me what am I missing, please?

**EDIT**
If I try to do `belgium_trains['Planned departure datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(belgium_trains['Planned departure datetime'])`, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Cannot mix tz-aware with tz-naive values

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
ValueError: Cannot mix tz-aware with tz-naive values

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/arrays/datetimes.py in objects_to_datetime64ns(data, dayfirst, yearfirst, utc, errors, require_iso8601, allow_object)
   2053             dayfirst=dayfirst,
   2054             yearfirst=yearfirst,
-> 2055             require_iso8601=require_iso8601,
   2056         )
   2057     except ValueError as e:

pandas/_libs/tslib.pyx in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime()

pandas/_libs/tslib.pyx in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime()

ValueError: Tz-aware datetime.datetime cannot be converted to datetime64 unless utc=True
```

However, if I update the above with `belgium_trains['Planned departure datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(belgium_trains['Planned departure datetime'], utc = True)`, it works. I still don't understand why I don't have this problem with the other variables.

Comment: Can you add the exact error with an actual data sample? Note that kwarg `utc=True` is to be set when converting string to datetime, not if you already have datetime dtype.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
Yes, I did set `utc` parameter to the string, i.e. `pd.to_datetime(piece of code that builds the datetime string, utc = True)`, but it doesn't work. The tricky part is that there is no error, the code snippet gets executed. It just refuses to convert that column and does not raise any error. It raises one when I try to treat it as a date and use methods to handle them